# How to write array data variables in postman API automation dynamically

Tags: arrays, json, automation, postman, postman-collection-runner

Here i have an issue in postman request body: `"cars": [{{cars}}]`

The json data file has this kind of inputs: `"cars":["axio","audi"]`

But this is not adding properly when I'm running postman collection; there the request body shows like this: `"cars":["axio,audi"]`.

Comment: How does the json file look like?

Comment: You should try something like `{{cars}}[0]` in the body. But @lucas-nguyen-17 is right, please show your json file.

Comment: in json file "cars":["axio","audi"] i have put like this